# How to export tile maps from Tiled which are compatible with `createObjectsFrom` in Phaser?

Tags: phaser-framework, tiled

The [function `createFromObjects`](http://docs.phaser.io/Phaser.Tilemap.html#createFromObjects)   has the `gid` as the second argument to be passed. The argument is used in the `createFromObjects` function in the following way:

```
createFromObjects: function (name, gid, key, frame, exists, autoCull, group, CustomClass, adjustY) {

    // ...

    for (var i = 0, len = this.objects[name].length; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (this.objects[name][i].gid === gid)
        {
           // ...
        }
    }
}
```

This expects the objects in the layer `name` to contain the field `gid` which points to the `gid` of the sprite to use.

However, the JSON file exported from Tiled does not contain any field `gid`.

Tiled only allows one to add custom properties to the Objects and there is no `gid` field present on the object to edit.

How can I include an `gid` in the exported JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question can be found [here](https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/issues/108).

> Indeed you can't set the gid of an object after you have placed it.
>
> You place these tile objects using the "Insert Tile Objects" tool,
>   after selecting the tile in your tileset.